# How can I animate the progressBar in a custom prototype cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation

I'm trying to have the following animation in my custom UITableViewCell:

> When a user checks off a task, the progressBar should go from 0.0 to 1.0 in 5 seconds

### **What I've tried**

**Doing the animation in the delegate method in the TableVC:**

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(item: indexSection!, section: indexRow!)) as? TaskCell
cell?.progressBar.setProgress(1.0, animated: true)
```

This doesn't work because it seems like the cell doesn't exist (`print(cell!)` gives a fatal error)

**Doing the animation in TaskCell.swift**

```
@IBAction func checkBoxAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if items![indexRow!].checked {
        delegate?.changeButton(state: false, indexSection: indexSection!, indexRow: indexRow!, itemID: itemID)
        
        UIView.self.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
            self.progressBar.setProgress(0.0, animated: true)
        }
    } else {
        delegate?.changeButton(state: true, indexSection: indexSection!, indexRow: indexRow!, itemID: itemID)
        
        UITableViewCell.animate(withDuration: 5.0) {
            self.progressBar.setProgress(1.0, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

This does set the progress bar, but it doesn't animate it. The progress bar abruptly changes. [This is what happens](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ff311p0o8lp9vr4/Screen%20Recording%202020-08-19%20at%2016.05.31.mov?dl=0)

Could anyone shine a light on what I'm doing wrong? Am I calling the animation function incorrectly or am I doing it in the wrong place?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

I have just created a simplified example and for me the following code works:

**CustomTableViewCell**

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
    
    @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    @IBAction func startButtonDidTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {
            self.progressView.setProgress(0.5, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewController**

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseID", for: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
        return cell
        
    }
}
```

Of course you need a proper storyboard configuration in order to run my code...

Comment: I have uploaded my sample project: https://github.com/finebel/AnimatingProgressView

Comment: Thank you finebel! This helped me a lot. I've tried to implement your code, but it seems like the problem lays in the fact where the code is called from. [Here is my GitHub project](https://github.com/mattttis/Carrot). When I call startActionII() from the start IBAction, it works perfectly. However, when I call that function from my delegate method, it does not animate. Any ideas?